# Can we clarify the [asp-classic] and [asp.net] tags for the uneducated?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Many of the questions being asked about [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) are being mistagged with the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic). Is there anyway the two can be disassociated or differentiated enough to prevent such a problem? For instance, would changing the tag name to [classic-asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classic-asp) be enough?

Comment: Why would that be enough? If it did work, it'd simply be because it made the tag more difficult to locate, which would decrease the chances that it would be used on the questions where it is appropriate.

Comment: Yes - that's why I asked: '*Is there any way...*'.

Comment: If you notice specific people repeatedly making the same mistake you can @message them to tell them to stop.

Comment: I do tend to message the OP and let them know - it's a losing battle!

Comment: We should create a classic-asp-classic tag for the classic asp questions, migrate pure asp.net questions to asp-classic, and retag asp.net-mvc questions asp.net.

Comment: Eh? '*migrate pure asp.net questions to asp-classic*' - ASP.NET is not asp-classic...

Comment: Could we not do something like if a question contains both [tag:asp.net] and [tag:asp] remove [tag:asp]? That would surely cut down on the edits I find myself doing just to keep the [tag:asp-classic] queue clean.

Comment: This post needs more love. As Paul said, fixing these problems is a losing battle. I stopped retagging them because there are too many and there's no ROI.

Comment: I suspect a large contributor to this problem is that ASP.NET and C# show as suggested tags for Classic ASP questions. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296198/change-suggested-tags-for-asp-classic

Answer (score 8):

> This problem is becoming a losing battle for the dedicated group of individuals trying to keep the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) queue free from unrelated questions about [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net).
>
> - [How many [ASP.Net] questions initially tagged [ASP] or [ASP-Classic]?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229251/how-many-asp-net-questions-initially-tagged-asp-or-asp-classic) *(It's constantly around the 50 per month mark at the moment)*

### The Synonym Problem

The problem is people now refer to ASP as [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) but because [asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) is a synonym of [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) it gets automatically changed and appears on the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) queue. There isn't much you can really do about this apart from make the [asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) tag a synonym of the [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) tag but then the opposite will start to happen.

*What does everyone else think?*

### <strike>Suggestion to Handle Instances of Grouped Tags</strike>

<strike>What we could do though is look for groupings so when people mark a question as [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) **(on the same question)** couldn't the system remove the [asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) tag?, this would cut down on a lot of false positives we see in the queue.</strike>

---

### I'm revisiting this post *(again)*

I've come to realise that the comment in the initial answer about changing the main tag to be [classic-asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classic-asp) instead of [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) and having the others as synonyms might actually work and I think it comes down to two things;

1. Historicially the term `"Classic ASP"` has always been in wider circulation then `"ASP Classic"` *(see this [Google Trend](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%22asp%20classic%22%2C%20%22classic%20asp%22&cmpt=q&tz=))*.

#### Interest over time

<sub>*(`"ASP Classic"` - Blue, `"Classic ASP"` - Red)*</sub>
[image: tag comparison chart]
*As you can see the graph clearly shows that `Classic ASP` has always been the more common variant.*

2. Because of the way the tag hint box works anyone typing `asp` will get [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) listing as their first option. This is fine but if someone goes to write `asp .net` *(because for some reason certain ones feel it needs a space)* you end up with [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) and [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net).

If point 2. was reversed so the master was [classic-asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classic-asp) instead of [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) I don't think this would happen as often. It would certain stop a lot of the false positives that end up in the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) queue.

> I should stress this won't stop people that write `asp .net` in the hint box as [asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) is still a synonym of [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic).

---

### Revisiting for the third time

Re-running the above query in Data Explorer it's interesting to note that the number of mis-tagged questions is steadily dwindling *(possible due to the efforts of the Classic ASP squad diligently editing / re-tagging questions)* the message is starting to get through.

*<sub>x = Number of questions and y = Time Period (in months)</sub>*
[image: Last 5 years showing initially incorrectly tagged ASP.Net question]

Comment: So, you want to blacklist [asp]? Might be a good idea, depending on how bad the problem is, but won't happen yet: The problem is not bad enough. Abandoning it though, that might work with moderator-help to break the synonym, synonymize asp-classic and classic-asp, and merge all the questions to them.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think that will work. My suggestion is to remove it where it is accompanied by asp.net on the same question. Any attempt to blacklist without that comparison will just send the issue to the other queue.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What is blacklisting?

Comment: @Paul: Disallowing re-creation of a tag. That's strictly a developer-only power, and thus used extremely sparingly.

Comment: Sorry, @Lankymart, missed your update to this. I think both of you have valid points; breaking (ASP from ASP-Classic) and reattaching the synonym (ASP to ASP.NET) and converting ASP-Classic to a synonym that points to Classic-ASP would be the best way forward. PS: Nice graph, Lanky ;o)

Comment: @Lankymart: regarding [**asp** *<space>* **.net**] - you can't legislate for the lunatic!

Comment: Maybe a solution like this could be implemented in ASP-classic vs ASP.net wars http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318948/961234

Comment: @Rafael Similar to [Keith's suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290592/692942) but will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

How about a warning when mixing [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) with [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or any other .NET-related tag? Something to the effect of:

> ASP Classic is not a .NET technology. Did you mean [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) or
>   [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)?

SO already has support for warnings (see the screenshot in [Can we get a warning when a user tags multiple DBMSs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286965/can-we-get-a-warning-when-a-user-tags-multiple-dbmss)) so I don't think this would be breaking the mold.

Comment: I have to admit, I've never seen that before and didn't even know SO could do it. This would be a viable option.