# Change suggested tags for asp-classic

Tags: discussion, suggested-tags

When writing a question about Classic ASP, these tags show among the suggested tags: [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). I suggest these tags be removed since .NET/C# has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

A lot of [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) questions are erroneously tagged as ASP.NET and C# (see [Can we clarify the asp-classic and asp.net tags for the uneducated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269402/can-we-clarify-the-asp-classic-and-asp-net-tags-for-the-uneducated)) and I suspect it's because of these suggested tags.

Comment: Actually, it's a positive feedback loop by an automated system.

Comment: [How it works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228974/did-stack-overflow-read-my-mind), and [a more short version of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-are-suggested-tags-chosen)