# Can we please remove the [asp] to [asp-classic] tag synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

It's gotten to where 80% of the new questions that come up for [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) have nothing on God's green earth to do with classic ASP. It's obvious that the OP simply typed "asp" (instead of "asp.net") in the tag field, and the system ever-so-helpfully replaced it with [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) for them.

*(For the uninitiated: ASP.Net and classic ASP have about as much in common as JavaScript and Java. Which is to say, their names are somewhat similar, and they serve some of the same purposes, and there all similarity ends.)*

[Previous requests to clarify the situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269402/can-we-clarify-the-asp-classic-and-asp-net-tags-for-the-uneducated) have been [largely ignored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296198/change-suggested-tags-for-asp-classic). I know this is not a high-traffic tag group, but as someone who knows a thing or two about classic ASP and jack squiddly about anything .Net, I'm reduced to editing out the spurious [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) tag from about three posts before my blood pressure goes up and I give up on StackOverflow for the day.

Pretty please, with a cherry on top: could we remove the synonym link between [asp] and [asp-classic], since clearly those terms are no longer synonymous?

Comment: Never really thought of JavaScript and Java serving similar purposes, but otherwise a good analogy. Isn't classic ASP obsolete?

Comment: Just checking the first page of [tag:asp-classic], it looks like there were three ASP.NET questions.

Comment: The "classic" part of the name sort of suggests "obsolescence" for whatever that designation is really worth. It doesn't mean nobody has questions about it anymore. Go tell the COBOL programmers their code is obsolete. Wouldn't they love if it were.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - It's about as obsolete as the screw in fuses in my home's fuse box. Would a breaker box be better? Absolutely. Will I have it replaced some day? Hopefully soon. Do I still need new fuses if one burns out? Yes, yes I do.

Comment: @Pluto: that's because I've already done a round of editing today.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: *some* of the same purposes, but yeah, the analogy does break a little if you look at it too closely. (That said, we used to have a Java applet to generate charts for us, which we replaced with a JavaScript-based utility when Java in the browser started getting increasingly untenable. So they do, indeed, *sometimes* serve the same purposes.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we clarify the \[asp-classic\] and \[asp.net\] tags for the uneducated?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269402/can-we-clarify-the-asp-classic-and-asp-net-tags-for-the-uneducated)

Comment: @Lankymart: good lord. Do you really want to shoot yourself in the foot like that? Are you *happy* with the status quo? Do you *like* meeting asp.net questions in the asp-classic queue? Sheesh.

Comment: @Lankymart this question gathered almost the same amount of views and certainly more votes than the oldest one in less than 6 hours. Do you really believe that shutting this discussion down (closing a question in meta makes it non-elegible for the community bulletin) which has the highest chances of being actioned is the correct path of action?

Comment: @Martha regardless of the supposed benefits it is still a duplicate question. I'm also not sure nuking the synonym is the right option in fact it will probably kill of the ASP community altogether.

Comment: @Braiam wow, so the fact it's clearly a duplicate doesn't matter? Besides marking it as a dup doesn't kill the conversation it just points people to the original discussion.

Comment: @Lankymart what? Are you sure you know how meta works? No attention = no discussion

Comment: @Lankymart: meta isn't the main site. As I've mentioned, there's no bounties here, so the ONLY way to bring new attention to an issue is to *post a new question*, hopefully with an engaging-enough title for people to actually read it. If it can get on the community bulletin, you don't mess with that, you *run with it*. (Plus there's the little tiny fact that **this is not a duplicate of the old question.** Answers don't make duplicates, *questions* do, and the old question doesn't mention synonyms.)

Comment: @Martha What you talking about the whole question is about synonyms and the relationship between [tag:asp] and [tag:asp-classic]. I still think just removing that relationship isn't the best approach. Still think renaming [tag:asp-classic] to [tag:classic-asp] would stop a lot of the false positives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've removed the synonym - let's see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Question: what happens now if people type "asp" in the tag field? Is it blacklisted at all, or did we just exchange "wrongly-tagged-with-asp-classic" for "uselessly-tagged-with-asp"?

Comment: @Martha it's been nuked, try editing a question and add [tag:asp] it warns you the tag doesn't exist and asks if you want to create it. What will happen now is some "tool" will come along create it again and we will have [tag:asp] and [tag:asp-classic] questions then someone will suggest a synonym and will be back at square one.

Comment: @Martha don't you just hate when I'm right... [tag:asp] has 5 questions as it stands, surprise surprise!!

Answer (score 22):

> It's obvious that the OP simply typed "asp" (instead of "asp.net") in the tag field, and the system ever-so-helpfully replaced it with asp-classic for them.

You are not wrong, 5772 renames since it was done, and given that [asp-classic] has just shy 10k questions this is more than clear that the synonym is causing disruption. I would prefer the [asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) blacklisted and the synonym removed.

Comment: I agree that blacklisting is a better option. 99% of users are going to type in [asp] and go. We are on the losing side of a statistics game by aliasing it to [asp-classic], but it's not obviously correct for it to map to [asp.net] either. Better to force an explicit choice. It violates Don't Make Me Think, but we're programmers, so thinking is our job.

Comment: [I've spoke about this in depth before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272481/692942) with no where near this much attention. A lot of the issue is in certain ones thinking `ASP .net` is a thing *(number of questions I've edited to replace use of `ASP .Net` to `ASP.Net` before then changing the tags to correct them is insane)*.

Comment: @Lankymart next time, ask with a fun title. Fun titles get all the attention! Of course that doesn't count cats, unicorns and turtles.

Comment: What's fun about this title?

Comment: @Lankymart [that it includes "pretty please"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/327122/1)

Comment: It doesn't, the question might *not* the title.

Comment: @Lankymart: the title used to include "pretty please" as well, until some spoilsport edited it out. (An even worse spoilsport tried to edit out all of my personal voice from the question as well, but thankfully someone corrected that before I saw it and blew my top.)

Comment: @Martha: I am both spoilsports. I suspect given your worsening temper, you are discovering that turning up to Meta in an already bad mood is not a great approach. We all want the best for Stack Overflow here - but let's do it congenially if we can. Less of the `effing` and `mindless fools` and `hope you are proud of yourself` too please - this is a professional environment.

Comment: @halfer: How does writing "pretty please" equate to "in an already bad mood"? I have a writing style, what's known as a "voice". I refuse to believe that I have to abandon that voice and in favor of something sterile, clinical, and boring, all in the name of "professionalism". (Though I do admit,  "mindless fools" *was* written in anger. Sorry.)

Comment: Thanks @Martha. I should have been more expansive about my edit. I don't mind people having a writing style at all on _Meta_, I think it's fine. My interpretation of your writing was that you seemed already exasperated, having drawn attention to this theme having been "ignored" before, as if that action was deliberate, and that someone was to blame for that. Given that you were reporting genuine frustrations about editing, "pretty please with a cherry on top" seemed somewhat saccharine and sardonic, and I felt that it would be better received without that.

Comment: I often make edits on the main site regarding tone, so as to maximise the chances of results - sometimes an accidental sharpness can turn people off, where they might otherwise have helped. It's worth remembering too that on Meta, good ideas are not always implemented - I often have feature requests that end up in the long grass, but _ces't la vie_.