# Warn [r] users from adding [dataframes] tag instead of [data.frame] tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-tips

[data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) is "*One of the most basic data structures in the R language*" (cited from the tags wiki), while [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) is something entirely different.

Problem is, that users (especially new ones) don't read the wiki (which emphasizes the difference) and keep tagging [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions with [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) way too often.

We are actively trying to clear [**this queue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+dataframes+-pandas+-python) but always being overwhelmed with the flood of new [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) /[dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) questions.

---

**The feature request:** I wonder if it possible to add a warning for a user that tries to tag a [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) question with [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes) and suggest [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame)  instead? Here's a draft, following the tone of [the sql popup tip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/1191259):

> Tip: Questions about the use of data.frames in R usually get better answers if they are tagged correctly, with the [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) tag instead of [dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframes).

---

### Update 14/3/2016

As for now, the [queue has been cleared](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318978/3001626) due to collaborate community effort (especially @Jaap). Though still looking for a more robust solution.

Also, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274634#274634) seems like both feasible and already tested possible solution that can be implemented in this case too.

Comment: I don't know much about R, but this sounds good.

Comment: Actually the [tag:dataframes] description now seems to be completely out of sync with its contents. The tag is full of Pandas/Python questions, whereas the description says something about big networking-related datasets.

Comment: Do you want help manually clearing the queue? I assume it's just a matter of editing `dataframes` to `data.frame`, i.e. global replace with some attention to detecting false positives?

Comment: @BenBolker We are already clearing the queue (well, mainly Jaap & KemyLand)- it was over 700 couple of days ago... But I feel that we should address the problem itself, rather just the symptoms.

Comment: Related [Retag R questions misstaged with \[tag:dataframes\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287681)

Comment: A small suggestion to the editors. While you are editing the post to remove the wrong tag, 1. Please take care to see if the post itself needs any edits. 2. Do close-vote/flag any off-topic ones while retagging. It will help remove the bad [data.frame] questions too.

Comment: I think that the only sane and definitive way to do this is just removing dataframe entirely and spawn two new tags, r-data.frame and python-dataframe.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure these are the only two languages where this tag can be used. I feel like these are probably the most common languages where it is being *misused*.

Comment: [There are 9 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+[dataframes]+-[pandas]+-[python]+closed%3A1) in the queue that are closed. Perhaps there can be a review if they are required for the site (casting reopen after editing) or they need to be removed (casting delete vote).

Comment: Well, you r guys got a problem with [r]+[dataframes], I'm offering a solution that helps your problem in a substantial manner.

Comment: @Braiam You could may be post as an answer and see how it goes then.

Comment: I wrote the example text for the tip, using "get better answers" even though I do not believe that to hold much truth (except insofar as answerers are a little less angry at the OP for writing a bad question). If we just wrote the tip in the imperative, like that Qs "should" be tagged correctly, we might get less people responding to it, I figure. Input and edits are welcome, of course. Could be an answer, too, I suppose, if there are competing ideas about the tip text.

Comment: the same thing happens with people requiring [drupal-webform] incorrectly using the [webforms] tag intended for asp.net. I manually edited these en masse to begin with and I occasionally go through them and manually edit all the new ones.

Answer (score 45):

The best way to solve a specific problem is to solve it generally. Rather than something special for [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), it would be great if tag editors could include lists or even linked lists of *"false friends"* synonyms (ie: [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) vs [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word), etc).

I'm thinking of a tag having lists like

> often mistaken for :

possibly with an optional, linked :

> when also tagged with :

Suggestions or warnings could then be dynamically generated for any tag combinations like these both now and in the future.  In this example,

- [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)

  - often mistaken for : [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame)

    - especially when also tagged with : [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
  - often mistaken for : [data.frame.foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame.foo)

    - especially when also tagged with : [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo), [foo++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo%2b%2b), [foo#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo%23)

This even allows distinction in the direction of confusion.  [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word), for example, is no doubt *much* more frequently misused to indicate [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) than the reverse (ie: [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) being used to indicate a pair of bytes).

Comment: I love the idea, but I'm afraid this would cause a lot of overhead and maybe 'cross-recommendations'. but maybe it's just a fear and easy to get as there's already a validation about the tags, adding a 'rule' may not be a large an overhead.

Comment: Good idea but.. tags are flat, non-hierarchical structures, and anything that moves tries to assign them other functions that smell like hierarchies are outrightly rejected.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't really know how they work, but we already have tag synonyms.  I don't see why having tag antonyms would be so bad, and that could serve a similar purpose.  It probably couldn't be used for cross tagging "You used r and dataframe, do you mean data.frame instead?", but could still be used to flag often misused tags "You used dataframe, do you maybe mean data.frame?"  They at least could clue a poster in that there may be more appropriate tags, or at least tell them to read what the tag is for.

Comment: Related: [Allow for Tag Antonyms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265601/allow-for-tag-antonyms)